# Como adicionar marcadores no meu mapa dinamicamente?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Bom galera, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile no AS, e estou utilizando do mapa para adicionar marcadores de cada localização de um novo formulário cadastrado, ou seja, ao realizar um cadastro eu mando junto minha latitude e longitude pro servidor. No mapa eu pego essa lista de objetos passando latitude e longitude e tento adicionar marcadores a estas posições, porem não consigo fazer isso de maneira dinâmica. Alguém pode me ajudar?

O codigo que gera o mapa com as localizaçoes do objeto:

```
private void gerarMapa(){

    for(int i = 0; i < palhetas.size(); i++) {
        double lat = Double.parseDouble( palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getLatitude() );
        double lon = Double.parseDouble( palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getLongitude() );
        LatLng locale = new LatLng( lat, lon );

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position( locale )
                .title( palhetas.get(i).getCodigo() )
                .snippet( palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getRua() )
                .icon( BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource( R.drawable.marker ) );
        mMap.addMarker( options );
        mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng( locale ) );
    }
}
```

Do jeito que esta, ele so marca a localização do primeiro objeto.
Outro problema que tenho é para pegar a localizaçao do objeto, preciso primeiro converter para double, pois meu objeto estou trazendo via gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type usuariosListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Palheta>>(){}.getType();
palhetas = gson.fromJson(response, usuariosListType);
```

Comment: O código para adicionar os marcadores parece estar correto. A lista palhetas esta com o .size() retornando mais que um?